# Access columns within exists clause

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
select * 
from AllUK  
where exists (select  * from AllCompanies where replace(AllUK.mobile,' ','')=replace(AllCompanies.mobile,' ',''))
```

I need to include the columns from the AllCompanies table in to my first select. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from AllUK a
join AllCompanies b
on a.mobile = b.mobile
```

exists is a boolean operation, so the clause you have above will always return all the results if there any records that can be joined accross the 2 tables. It's hard to tell what you're really trying to achieve.

Also, putting string operations on columns within exists and joins is not best practice because the compiler has to do the operation on every row & column at run time. Might be better to create a temp table to hold the replaced values and then join on that.